# Dev stack/ media wiki on Apache server

Tags: apache, mediawiki, openstack

I have devstack which is the development environment for Openstack on my Ubuntu machine 12.04 LTS. I recently installed mediawiki on my laptop. The problem now seems to be that every time I run /etc/init/apache2 start, the server starts and points to Openstack login. I want to instantiate the mediawiki server.

Is this possible? Can a single piece of hardware run two servers? Do I have to virtualization here?

The solution that I could think of on top of my head is that, there must be a file which points which server to instantiate. If this is the case, I am not able to think which file has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at LXC.  And create a linux container for the devstack environment.

Alternatively something akin to cowbuilder may work well.